# Inverting a color picture?

Tags: python, image

I think I'm missing something here, I can invert a grayscale & black & white picture. But for some reason, I'm missing the piece to invert a color picture.

I'm sure it's just one line but I must be having a brain fart because I can't figure it out.

```
from images import Image

def invert2(image):
    for y in range(image.getHeight()):
        for x in range(image.getWidth()):
            (r, g, b) = image.getPixel(x, y)
            r = 255 - r
            g = 255 - g
            b = 255 - b
            lum = r + g +b
           image.setPixel(x, y, (r, g, b))

def invert(image):
    """Inverts an image to its negative."""
    for y in range(image.getHeight()):
        for x in range(image.getWidth()):
            (r, g, b) = image.getPixel(x, y)
            average = (255-r+255-g+255-b)//3
            image.setPixel(x,y, (average, average, average))

def blackAndWhite(image):
    """Converts an image to black and white."""
    blackPixel = (0, 0, 0)
    whitePixel = (255, 255, 255)
    for y in range(image.getHeight()):
        for x in range(image.getWidth()):
            (r, g, b) = image.getPixel(x, y)
            average = (r + g + b) // 3
            if average < 128:
                image.setPixel(x, y, blackPixel)
            else:
                image.setPixel(x, y, whitePixel)

def grayscale(image):
    """Converts an image to grayscale."""
    for y in range(image.getHeight()):
        for x in range(image.getWidth()):
            (r, g, b) = image.getPixel(x, y)
            r = int(r * 0.299)
            g = int(g * 0.587)
            b = int(b * 0.114)
            lum = r + g + b
            image.setPixel(x, y, (lum, lum, lum))     

def main():
    filename = input("Enter the image file name: ")
    image = Image(filename)

    # Invert image
    invert(image)
    image.draw()

    # Convert to greyscale, then invert
    """grayscale(image)
    invert(image)
    image.draw()"""

    # Convert to black and white, then invert
    """blackAndWhite(image)
    invert(image)
    image.draw()"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

As in like this?

```
def main():
    filename = input("Enter the image file name: ")
    image = Image(filename)

    # Invert image
    invert2(image)
    image.draw()
    invert(image) 
    image.draw()

    # Convert to greyscale, then invert
    """grayscale(image)
    invert(image)
    image.draw()"""

    # Convert to black and white, then invert
    """blackAndWhite(image)
    invert(image)
    image.draw()"""
```

Comment: `invert2` looks good but you don't use it.

Comment: What do you mean? The code works except it's not inverting color pictures.

Comment: I mean you don't call `invert2` anywhere in `main`. Is your test picture using 24 bit color format?

Comment: Awwww ok gotcha, let me try that.

Comment: `invert` would create some inverted **grayscale** image so don't call that before you call `invert2` if you whish a converted color picture.

Comment: Still didn't work no invert of a color photo using RGB

Comment: Is this python code? If so, try to add the python tag to your question. I'm not familiar with the syntax and variables involved, in the theory it looks good to me...

Comment: Yes, it's python, I added my tag. Sorry, I'm still learning this site and how to properly use it.

Comment: No problem. Hopefully you attract with the added tag some python pros who can help you further;)

Comment: Are you using `images.py` from [here](https://github.com/tradaviahe1982/Python_Basic_For_EveryOne)? Assuming your are, the type of the input image must GIF. The method `getPixel` raises an exception: 
`"'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'"`. It's simple to fix the code (note: it's not in your code). If you don't see any error message, it's hard to tell if this is the problem. Your `invert2` implementation is correct.